# How to add imageView dynamically to scroll view which has linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-imageview

How to add imageView dynamically using java code to the LinearLayout with scroll view? I want my images side by side but when detected it's edge of the phone, add new row but I dont seem to find any answer.. all they say is just adding dynamically either vertically or horizontally but no newline..

anyone would want to help me? :( I'm new to this.

my XML code below :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutWordsVert"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutWordsHori"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/saya"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_darkgreen1"
                android:src="@drawable/me"
                android:padding="1dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

EXPECTED VIEW:

```
|---------|---------|---------|
| image 1 | image 2 | image 3 |
|---------|---------|---------|
| image 4 | image 5 | image 6 |
|---------|---------|---------|
```

Comment: looking at what you want, you should go for gridView

Comment: yes, you should go for recyclerview instead of scroll view and use gridlayout manager

Comment: err.. so is it gridView better or recyclerview? o.o @rj

Comment: @Akbar er apparently i can't tag both in one comment..

Comment: Actually in Recyclerview you will have to use grid-layout manager to do this.

Comment: recyclerView is imporoved version of listView/gridView, But if you are putting the logic of recycling then it doesn't matter much whether you use recyclerView or gridView

Comment: okay i just googled.. i think i'd better use gridView easier.. but thanks because i learned new thing.. @Akbar

Comment: will add code for gridview in few secs for your reference, check that out

Comment: ooooo okayokay thanks peeps... @rj

Comment: theres an easier way. you add another imageview with height, and width set to 0dp and give it an id. That will be hidden initially. When you want to show it you can programaticaly set the desired width and height and it will show.

Comment: @tasos you meant hiding images? i got like 200 images :x

Comment: Im just going by the (XML code) you posted. you only have 1 ImageView inside a scrollview. you need to create another layout and inflate it using gridview.

Comment: @Tasos ooo sorry my fault.. okayokay.. thank you so much for your reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what your MainActivity.java would look like,

```js
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    ArrayAdapter<String> nosAdapter;
    GridView gridView;

    int images[] = { R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three,
            R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five, R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven,
            R.drawable.eight, R.drawable.nine, R.drawable.ten, R.drawable.zero,
            R.drawable.blank };

    MyGridViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridView);
        adapter = new MyGridViewAdapter(this, images);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item at pos "+pos+" clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

This would be your GridView Adapter,

```js
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int[] images;
    Context context;

    public MyGridAdapter(Context context, int[] images) {
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView;
    LinearLayout outerLayout;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_my_images,null);
    }

    imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);

    imageView.setImageResource(images[pos]);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

and finally the activity_main.xml

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/GridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="3dp" >
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

layout file the grid, grid_my_images.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivGridMyApp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" /></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: wao i didnt know i still need adapter.. gosh where whould i put this? haha normal java class right?

Comment: btw it implements onItemClickListener where actually my code implements onClickListener isit the same?

Comment: put that class in the same package where your activity classes are or you can put it in any package and access it as long as it is defined "public". And the onItemClickListener is a callBack method of gridView adapter which will be called when you click on an item, here an image.

Comment: onItemClickListener() is a callback method of the gridView adapter and the onClickListener() is a callback method of a view like e.g. a button

Comment: yes i have question omigosh.. i just run it just now my grid view is showing, pictures is showing but the size of the picture is too tall infact it didnt stretch my pic but just the frame thing very long.. idk how to explain and the weird thing is, the pictures starts to jumble up when i scroll up scroll down press here and there.. :O and my toast is not coming out :O @rj

Comment: Replace the line in adapter class with this, image.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Comment: You can also put some hardcoded values for height and width

Comment: i replaced edy.. not working.. but that's not a big problem.. the problem now the images all jumble up @@ isit meant to be jumble? i dont want.. because whenever i scroll down then scroll back up all jumbled..

Comment: I will post the code in the afternoon, till then you can search over Google how to inflate layout in adapter, so that a layout file will have the design you need for a grid

Comment: thankss.. but we got timezone difference.. so idk when is your afternoon but it's okay.. i'll wait.. thank you so much.. @rj

Comment: have you forgotten me? :(

Comment: i think you coded wrongly the R.id.IvImage ... at the imageview = imageview find by id... in the adapter..

Comment: YAY THANKS now the images are not changing itself when i scroll! million thanks!!!!!